# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')

Tags: vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')
```

How can I call `showOpenDialog()` with the most minimal changes?

I am using the new Quasar/Electron with Webpack 5.

Here is the openFile() method in my vue file:

```js
    openFile () {
      window.electronApi.dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title: 'Load File',
        properties: ['openFile']
      }).then(result => {
        const filename = result.filePaths[0]

        if (filename) {
          const extension = getExtensionName(filename)
          console.log(extension)
        } else {
          console.log('No file selected')
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(FILE + 'Error: ' + err)
      })
    },
```

And here is what is declared in electron-preload.js:

```js
import { contextBridge} from 'electron'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronApi', {
  dialog: require('electron').dialog,
  showOpenDialog: require('electron').showOpenDialog
})
```

Comment: Can you try `require('electron').remote.dialog` instead of `require('electron').dialog`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal what if require('electron').remote is undefined?

Comment: @JGInternational try using ```import { dialog } from '@electron/remote'```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for @creative learner's idea! This works!

```js
import { contextBridge} from 'electron'
import { dialog } from '@electron/remote' 

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronApi', {
  dialog: dialog
})
```